# jQuery Mobile collapsibleset not working

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

This is my listview: https://jsfiddle.net/QkiZ/eu6t61o3/
It's working well but one thing doesn't work like it said in jQuery Mobile docs. `data-role="collapsibleset"` shoud make open only one list at time but I can open all list at time.

Comment: I am unable to replicate the what you described. When I expand the first collapsed list, it opens. It does not open other collapsed lists. Were you expecting the first one to close?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing collapsible sets with lists and some items that are not collapsible. This is not directly supported by jQM, you could add one event handler that gives you the desired functionality:

Give the container an ID so we ca use it in selectors:

```
<div data-role="collapsibleset" id="theset">
```

Then add an **[expand handler](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#event-expand)** to all the collapsibles within the container. When an item is expanded, **[collapse](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#method-collapse)** all others that are not this one:

```
$('#theset [data-role="collapsible"]').on("collapsibleexpand", function( event, ui ) {
    var that = $(this);        
    $('#theset [data-role="collapsible"]').each(function(idx,elem){
        if (elem != that[0]){
            $(elem).collapsible( "collapse" );
        }
    });
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/eu6t61o3/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Since your using `listview` for your content, the accordion operation will not collapse the other expanded sets. See example: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/listview-collapsible-item-indented/

You can add this function back with JQuery, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").click(function(){
        var item = $(this);
        $("li.ui-collapsible").not(item).collapsible( "collapse" );
    });
});
```

Updated your example: https://jsfiddle.net/eu6t61o3/2/

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, it's hard to tell where it is failing. I would try moving it to your panel `div` like so:

```
<div data-role="panel" data-display="overlay" data-position-fixed="true" id="mypanel">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mypanel .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").click(function(){
            var item = $(this);
            $("#mypanel li.ui-collapsible").not(item).collapsible( "collapse" );
        });
    });
    </script>
    // Other Panel HTML
</div>
```

Comment: Where I can insert this script? It doesn't work when it in header.

Comment: You can wrap it in `<script></script>` in your `<head>` section. You can also place it as the last item before `</body>`.

Comment: In both cases it doesn't work on website. Look here http://www.greencookies.pl/o-stronie2.html?template=greencookies-mobile.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: In FireFox, I see: `TypeError: $ is not a function, var item = $(this); Line 222, Col 20` This would suggest that JQuey is not loading or something is wrong there.

Comment: Do you see any Errors in the Console? What browsers are you testing with?